# How to split index of array with multiple objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have multiple fruits with quantity and fixed price (50). Fruit is chosen from drop down menu. Upon pressing enter button, javascript code runs where fruit is pushed into an array along with its quantity and price.

```
<select id="fruit">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>

<button id="opt" onclick="Fruit()">Enter</button>
```

I have managed to store them in an array as:

```
var storeArr = [];
quantity = 10;
selectItem = false;

function Fruit() {
    var selectedFruit;
    selectItem = document.getElementById("fruit");
    selectedFruit = selectItem.options[selectItem.selectedIndex].value;

    storeArr.push([selectedFruit,quantity,50]);
    quantity = quantity + 5;
    printArray();
}

function printArray(){
    const iterator = storeArr.values();
        for (const value of iterator) {
            console.log("values: "+value);
        }
}
```

It results exactly like I want to store the items. After multiple selections from the drop down list say apple, banana, apple etc, The output looks like this:

```
values: apple, 10, 50
values: banana, 15, 50
values: apple, 20, 50
```

Now I want to access say index 1 (banana, 15, 50) based on variable "selectedFruit" and split these values. I am not able to figure out a way to do that. Can anyone help?

Comment: The thing is, your values are already *split*. Are you having trouble selecting them?

Comment: index 1 = `storeArr[1]`

Comment: what do you want, can you express it more clearly?

Comment: I want to access index to get multiple values stored on it For example, I want to get values on index 1 that are "banana, 15, 50".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `storeArr` looks something like this `[['apples', 10, 50], ['banana', 15, 50]]`. It is an array of arrays. So in order to access item's quantity at index 1, you have to do `storeArr[1][1]`.

A suggestion would be to have a little modification in the Fruit function

```js
function Fruit() {
    var selectedFruit;
    selectItem = document.getElementById("fruit");
    selectedFruit = selectItem.options[selectItem.selectedIndex].value;

    storeArr.push({selectedFruit, quantity,fixedPrice: 50});
    quantity = quantity + 5;
    printArray();
}
```

Notice we are pushing an object into the array, so you can access required item's quantity like `storeArr[1].quantity`

`storeArr` will be of this form now,

```js
[
    {
        selectedFruit: 'apple',
        quantity: 10,
        fixedPrice: 50
    },
    {
        selectedFruit: 'banana',
        quantity: 15,
        fixedPrice: 50
    },
    {
        selectedFruit: 'orange',
        quantity: 20,
        fixedPrice: 50
    }
]
```

And if you want to access an object based on the fruit's name, you can use `find`

```js
const banana = storeArr.find(obj => obj.selectedFruit === 'banana');
```

and it's quantity using `banana.quantity`

Comment: If I write it as 
storeArr.push({selectedFruit, quantity,50}); 
then it generates an error that "Uncaught ReferenceError: Fruit is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick()"

Comment: Hi @Masu I have fixed that issue, needed to give a key for the last element (fixedPrice). Check now and let me know if it works :)

Comment: Is there any way to get index of the pushed data so I can pass that index instead of hardcoding it with 0 or 1 and so on in storeArr[1].quantity?

Comment: Index of which object ? If you need to get quantity of apple for example, you can use ````find```` like in the answer and then get its quantity using ````.quantity````

Comment: I need to get index of arrays stored on indexes of array. If "banana, 15, 50" is pushed in array at index 2, how can I get this index? IndexOf() does not work as there are multiple values stored on index 2.

Comment: Your suggestions helped me to resolve the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 2:** As the OP wants to retain the structure

```
storeArr: [
    ['apple', 10, 50]
    ['banana', 15, 50]
    ['orange', 20, 50]
]
```

Add a function to your code

```
function getFruitDetails(fruit) {
    for(var i = 0; i < storeArr.length; i++) {
        if (storeArr[i][0] === fruit) {
            return storeArr[i]
        }
    }
}
```

And use like this

`getFruitDetails(selectedFruit)[1]` or `getFruitDetails(selectedFruit)[2]`

**UPDATE:** As per the OP's recent comment, you can change `storeArr` to an object, instead of an array. The structure of that object should look like

```
storeArr: {
    "apple": [10, 50],
    "banana": [15, 50],
    "orange": [20, 50]
}
```

and access like `storeArr[selectedFruit][0]` and so on...

**ORIGINAL:**

However, it looks like you have an array inside array which can be accessed like `storeArr[1][0]`, `storeArr[1][1]` and so on... (for `banana`)

The above will work if your array looks like

```
storeArr: [
    ['apple', 10, 50]
    ['banana', 15, 50]
    ['orange', 20, 50]
]
```

**UPDATE 3:** Although not recommended, but as asked by the OP

You can replace

```
storeArr.push([selectedFruit,quantity,50]);
```

in your code with

```
var recentIndex = storeArr.push([selectedFruit, quantity, 50]) - 1
```

to access the index of the last (recently) pushed element in the array.

But if you are considering `banana, 15, 50` as a string

```
storeArr: [
    ["apple, 10, 50"]
    ["banana, 15, 50"]
    ["orange, 20, 50"]
]
```

The following should work:

```
var items = storeArr[1].split(', ');
```

`items[0]` will be `banana`, `items[1]` will be `20` and so on...

Comment: Yes, multiple arrays are stored on each index of an array. I want to access lets say index 1 based on fruit name say 'banana' using variable "selectedFruit". As it is array inside array, I am confused how to do it. I cannot write storeArr[selectedFruit][0].

Comment: I have updated my answer, let me know if you need help in creating the suggested structure?

Comment: I cannot use storeArr[] as object because nothing is hardcoded and values are being passed through variables. Secondly using storeArr[selectedFruit][0] generates error: "caught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at <function name>"

Comment: @Masu I have updated my answer again, does this help?

Comment: I am preferring to follow the original approach you suggested. There is one problem that I do not want to hard code i as storeArr[1][1]. Instead, is there a way to pass in first dimension, the index of array where the inner array is located?

Comment: @Masu You can get the index of the recently pushed element by replacing `storeArr.push([selectedFruit,quantity,50]);` in your code to `var recentIndex = storeArr.push([selectedFruit, quantity, 50]) - 1`. Then you can pass `recentIndex` as the first dimension index. Although, this is not a suggested approach.

Comment: This is a fine way however, if I have pushed an array at index 5 and need to access array on index 2, this will not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205003/discussion-between-akshit-mehra-and-masu).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you could place the values inside an object.
That way you can have something like the following:

```
[{
    fruit:'apple', 
    quantity: 4, 
    price: 50
},
{
    fruit:'banana'
    quantity: 1,
    price: 50
}]
```

For instance,

```
function printArray(){
    const iterator = storeArr.values();
    const arrayOfObjects = []
        for (const value of iterator) {
            const splitFruitString = value.split(',')
            arrayOfObjects.push({
                fruit: splitFruitString[0],
                quantity: splitFruitString[1],
                price: splitFruitString[2]
            })
        }
}
console.log(arrayOfObjects);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not store an array of objects instead of an array of arrays.

At the moment your array looks like this:

```
[
  [
    'apple',
    10,
    50,
  ],
  [
    'banana',
    15,
    50,
  ],
]
```

You say you're having difficulty accessing each set of values. While you could do something like `storeArr[0][1]` to get the quantity of the first fruit, it's more obvious if you stored an object for each fruit like so:

```
[
  {
    name: 'apple',
    quantity: 10,
    price: 50,
  },
  {
    name: 'banana',
    quantity: 15,
    price: 50,
  },
]
```

This way, you can access each the quantity of the second fruit like so:

```
storeArr[1].quantity
```

This is clearer than using a 2 dimensional array.